# Rollback to tag-only revision fails to restore the body text present in that revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, rollbacks

A question was [edited to a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45246953/revisions). It was subsequently [rolled back to a past revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45246953/revisions). After 11 minutes, the new question is still present.

A Rollback war is not occurring. The browser was refreshed to ensure it was not an oversight on my part (Firefox 54.0.1 (32-bit) on Windows).

I don't rollback often, and I cannot recall the last time I used it. Looking at the history, it states *"Rollback to Revision 2"*, and revision two is the correct one. I believe I used it correctly.

Is rollback working as expected?

Comment: ok, I just made it look even more confusing...

Comment: @Shog9 6 minutes after your change it is still showing new version...

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing stuff, bear with me

Comment: I wonder if it is just something special with this particular question or if it is broken for all question rollbacks.

Comment: I rolled back to rev #1, just to verify *that* works. Writing up details

Comment: Nah, this is good for documenting weird hiccups the system has, and also a soapbox for Shog to tell all his gory histories. See^

Comment: This problem *can be* reproduced, as seen on Shog answer.

Comment: Rolling back to suggested edits that were Improved has always been buggy, this isn't new.

Comment: I wrote up a (possibly) related bug, see the linked items in the sidebar. Has a developer looked at this and confirmed it as a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed - details on MSE: [Cannot rollback to a suggested edit which was 'improved' by a reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288734/cannot-rollback-to-a-suggested-edit-which-was-improved-by-a-reviewer/311137#311137)

---

This is pretty odd...

The edit you attempted to roll back to was a tag-only edit (removed the redhat and linux tags).

That edit was *approved* [by the author of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16791151), who approved it using the "Improve Edit" feature in review - during which he also replaced nearly the entire contents of the question with a different question.

Now, normally this should result in a revision that, if rolled back to, would pull the body text from the *previous* revision (revision #1) of the question. However, it clearly pulls it from the *subsequent* revision instead!

Internally, these two revisions - rev#2 and rev#3 - have the exact same timestamp, but different IDs.

I've reproduced this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/240440/revisions

Note the functionally-identical scenario in revisions #6 through #8:

1. Tag-only edit
2. Approved by "Improve" that also replaces post body and further modifies tags
3. Subsequent rollback rolls back *only tags*
4. Rolling back the post body requires selecting a revision prior to the tag-only edit.

(I had to modify tags in step #2, as otherwise rollback to the tag-only edit would *silently do nothing at all!*)

Note that this behavior does *not* exist if the edit is approved *prior to* further editing, as demonstrated in revisions #9 through #11:

1. Tag-only edit, approved but not improved
2. Edit that replaces post body
3. Rollback to tag-only edit works as expected.

There's a previous report of this bug on MSE: [Cannot rollback to a suggested edit which was 'improved' by a reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288734/cannot-rollback-to-a-suggested-edit-which-was-improved-by-a-reviewer)