# Edit-rollback fails and creates bizarre "disappearing edit"

Tags: bug, edits, rollbacks

Yesterday, a user edited [this newly-posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53281321/1709587) (10k only) to add a relevant tag and also a whole bunch of inappropriate backticks. I decided to revert this by clicking the "edit" link next to revision 1 in the question history, readding the relevant tag, and clicking "Save Edits".

It looked like the edit had succeeded; I saw the question in its edited state, with the backticks gone. But when I refreshed, the backticks were back! It was as if nothing had changed at all.

... but when I viewed the revision history, my edit was still there, showing the removal of the backticks. In other words, the revision history of the post and its final state were out of sync with each other.

So next, I clicked the ordinary "edit" button on the question, manually removed every backtick, and saved. This worked and got the post to the final state that I wanted... but it also *retroactively* changed the diff for my previous edit, turning it into an empty edit.

Today, something similar happened on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226112/1709587). The first step (I attempt an edit-rollback, and nothing actually happens) was basically the same as yesterday: I clicked the "edit" link next to revision 1, readded the `vba` tag, and hit save... and as you can see in revision 4, the edit didn't stick. After that, the chain of events diverges slightly. I decided to *again* try clicking the "edit" link next to revision 1, readding the `vba` tag, and hitting save, and *again* nothing happened. Then I tried going through the exact same process a third time, within the grace period of my second try, and *that* time it stuck, updating revision 5 to the state you can now see.

Based on these bizarre experiences, I think there's *something* currently wrong with the way that edit-rollbacks work, perhaps broken recently. Even if I've confused myself about precisely what I did and some of the details I give above are wrong - which I concede is possible - as far as I know it should never be possible to create an empty edit, so there has to be *something* wrong, and hopefully the first link here provides a staff member with a hook from which to start figuring out what.

Comment: Possibly related to all of the other recent rollback related bugs

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, there are others? Links? I don't see anything else this year in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollbacks+bug

Comment: [Rollback to tag-only revision fails to restore the body text present in that revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352656/4639281), as well as the linked questions.

Comment: Yeah there seem to be a couple of these under the rollbacks tag... e.g. [Rollback does not rollback to the correct revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364881/rollback-does-not-rollback-to-the-correct-revision), which perhaps not coincidentally also involves tags.

Comment: I see my definition of "recent" may need adjusting.

Comment: Why are you editing to rollback? There's a rollback button for every version on the history page. Using it makes for a *much* more clear edit history as to what exactly is happening, even if you have to rollback, then perform some other edit. When you edit to rollback, people looking at the edit history have to look carefully at the diff view, matching each and every single difference in order to see that, yes, you did actually do the equivalent of a rollback. It's a *lot* more work for everyone looking at the history, and more work for you (a rollback is just click-> confirm click-> done).

Comment: @Makyen Hmm? I don't do enough rollbacks to know what the difference in outcome is between clicking the revision's rollback button, then using the post's edit button to edit (which is what I think you're proposing?) and using the revision's edit button in the first place. I'm sure clicking "rollback" first is *not* less work for me (how could it be? It adds more clicks and doesn't *remove* any actions from the workflow.), but in what way does it produce a nicer history for others? If the revision edit button should never be used, why does it exist in the first place?

Comment: @TinyGiant in the internet, a thousand years can happen in a second.